# How to estimate how long an rsync of 427GB directory comprises of 470k subdirectories and 4476k files would take?

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, rsync

- I have a directory that I want to `rsync` over a 1Gb LAN to another machine.
- The rsync command is

  /usr/bin/rsync -a --delete --numeric-ids --relative --delete-excluded --rsh=/usr/bin/ssh root@*machine*.local:*source-dir* *destination-dir*
- This 427GB directory comprises of 470571 subdirectories and 4476474 files.
- The rsync didn't finish over a weekend.

**How can I estimate how long the rsync would take?**

The OS on both machines is CentOS 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time for some rough [Fermi estimates](https://what-if.xkcd.com/84/) with [GNU units](https://www.gnu.org/software/units/) as a calculator.

Pretend this was one big archive and it could copy sequentially. 1 Gb link, say with overhead the transfer gets 70% of that.

```
You have: (.7 / 8) GB /s
You want: hr / 427 GB
        reciprocal conversion
        * 1.3555556
        / 0.73770492
```

But it took way longer than an hour and a half. With lots of small files, metadata IO dominates transfer times, and these are small on average:

```
You have: 427 GB / 4476474
You want: kB
        * 95.387575
        / 0.010483546
```

Assume rsync has to do an IO per file or directory to check metadata, and another IO to copy it. You didn't describe storage, but say worst case of a SATA spinner, so 50 IOPS.

```
You have: 50 / s
You want: hr / (2 * 5000000)
        reciprocal conversion
        * 55.555556
        / 0.018
```

Two and a quarter days is actually low, if you said you stopped it on the 3rd day.

My educated guesses will get a lot of things wrong: system load, storage capability, how rsync's algorithms perform with this many files, how many files were deleted in the target. But it helps to get close to the order of magnitude of work done, then compare to the system's limits.

---

About copying this faster: copy archives or images, not files. Much less file metadata, and a sequential copy.  For example, take a LVM snapshot, and use `dd` to pipe the entire file system over the network.  Not nearly as flexible as rsync, can only copy over the entire volume.

Comment: Thanks for an excellent answer, @JohnMahowald. As for the last suggestion: alas, this rsync is part of an rsnap backup, so there's not much I can do besides scrapping the whole backup infrastructure,

Comment: Your responsibility includes informing the owners of these data how old backups are. If copies many days old does not meet recovery objectives, rethinking backups may be required. Or everyone understands this copy takes a week or so.

Answer (score 1):

Include the option `-v` and `--progress`

This will display the count-down timer while the copy process is in progress.

```
user@ubuntu:/opt/$ rsync -v --progress test.iso /tmp/
test.iso
  1,459,486,720 100%   51.41MB/s    0:00:27 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)

sent 1,459,843,134 bytes  received 35 bytes  53,085,206.15 bytes/sec
total size is 1,459,486,720  speedup is 1.00
```

In this example, the copy process will take 27 seconds (`0:00:27`) to complete. The count-down timer started from 27 seconds (copy progress 0%) and went down all the way to zero seconds (copy progress 100%). After completion, the 27 seconds was re-displayed as an indicator that the whole process took 27 seconds in total.

Another option is to pipe the `rsync` command to `pv` command

Reference: [Here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/show-progress-during-file-transfer/)

Comment: I don't want to know how long it'd take after it's finished (a `time`  command could do that), but to estimate how long it'd take beforehand - to know if the
 three days it ran - before I stopped the `rsync` - is to be expected.

Comment: If the copy process takes 50 minutes to complete, the count-down timer will start from 50mins going down up to zero. Therefore from the start of the copy process, you would have already determined that the entire process will take 50 minutes to complete.

Answer (score 1):

The estimate is (time to gather file info) + (time to write the data).

Time to gather file info:

Run `ls -lR >/dev/null` over the files.  That's a good estimate of how long it will take to `lstat()` each file.

Time to write the data:

Write times are usually slower than reads, so measure the write speed at the destination with `dd bs=8k count=53375000 if=/dev/zero of=filename.data`. (The count times 8k is about 427GB)

You can also factor in the transmission time, but a 1G link may be faster than the drives can write, so it becomes a non-factor.   Of course, if the link was slower than the write speed (say, a 9600 baud modem), that will be the deciding factor.